SNTP not working on Cisco SG220
I'm trying to make SNTP work on a Cisco SG220 switch by using a NTP server pool ("0.europe.pool.ntp.org"). When I put the IP address of a NTP server in that pool, it works fine. When I put the proper FQDN to the pool, the system time does not get in sync.
For your reference, I have gateway and DNS addresses configured properly (ping for "0.europe.pool.ntp.org" succeeds).
Ideas?

Ideas? the switch has debug logging, have you reviewed it?

@GregAskew Unfortunately the switch does not have a debug option for NTP. Also, the protocol is refered to as "SNTP".
